# Changing function on a button using detachPress / attachPress

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement for my app and I need to change the event handler of a common button depending on the status of the workflow.

Basically I need to change the function called when you press the button and vice-versa and was looking to achieve this by using the event handler functions **detachPress** and **attachPress**.

https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Button/methods/detachPress
https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Button/methods/attachPress

My Button (XML View):

```
<Button text="Edit" width="50%" id="_editButtonEmail" press="editPIN"/>
```

On my controller I want to change the function **editPIN** by **cancelEditPIN**.

Some things I've tried:

```
    editPIN: function(oControlEvent) {
       //change button
       var editButton = this.getView().byId("_editButtonEmail");
       //detach this function on press
       editButton.detachPress(editButton.mEventRegistry.press[0].fFunction);
       editButton.attachPress(this.cancelEditPIN());
    }

    cancelEditPIN: function() {
       //do something else
    }
```

Also

```
editPIN: function(oControlEvent) {
   //change button
   var src = oControlEvent.getSource();
   src.detachPress(this.editPIN());
   src.attachPress(this.cancelEditPIN());
}
```

None of these seem to work and if I check my console the function **editPIN** is still attached to my **mEventRegistry** press event.

[image]

Comment: isn't it easier to branch off *inside* the attached handler and just put an `if(status) do_this() else do_that()`?

Comment: @Jorg I believe that is easier yes, I'm thinking of making an if statement by checking the button's text with **this.getView().byId("_editButtonEmail").getText()** and calling the appropriate function. That should work.

Comment: What drives the text changing? I'd use the same variables as that. Text is unreliable once you start translating the app if you're using the internationalisation mechanisms etc.

Comment: @Jorg I'm driving text changes by calling the i18n file variables with **oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle()** and setting by **oBundle.getText("editCancelPIN")**, these will be the same on either language. 
I believe that I got this working now so I'll be posting a solution soon. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things worse than checking your GUI texts to determine what action should be done.

A different approach uses two buttons. Only one is visible at a time

```
<Button
    text="{i18n>editPIN}"
    visible="{= ${myModel>/State} === 'show' }"
    press="editPIN" />
<Button
    text="{i18n>editCancelPIN}"
    visible="{= ${myModel>/State} === 'edit' }"
    press="cancelEditPIN" />
```

In this case `{myModel>/State}` is a local JSON model where the current state of your workflow is stored.

---

If you really want to use your attach/detach approach: It probably didn't work because you were calling the methods while passing them as a parameter to attach/detach. So for example try `src.detachPress(this.editPIN);` instead of `src.detachPress(this.editPIN());`

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea from [@Jorg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502613/jorg), I created another function **checkPIN** with an if statement that compares the text in the button and then fires the appropriate function depending on it.

I do have to phrase that I am using my i18n file to provide texts to my view, this way my textID will not change on whatever language the user is using.

My Button:

```
<Button text="Edit" width="50%" id="_editButtonEmail" press="checkPIN"/>
```

My Controller:

```
    checkPIN: function(oControlEvent) {
        var src = this.getView().byId("_editButtonEmail").getText();
        var oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
        //call cancelEditPIN
        var editCancelPinText = oBundle.getText("editCancelPIN");
        //call editPIN
        var editPinText = oBundle.getText("editPIN");
        //change button
        if (src === editPinText) {
            this.editPIN(oBundle);

        } else if (src === editCancelPinText) {
            this.cancelEditPIN(oBundle);
        }
    },
    editPIN: function(oBundle) {
        //do stuff here

        //change button text
        var editButton = this.getView().byId("_editButtonEmail");
        editButton.setText(oBundle.getText("editCancelPIN"));
    },
    cancelEditPIN: function(oBundle) {
        //do different stuff here

        //change button text
        var editButton = this.getView().byId("_editButtonEmail");
        editButton.setText(oBundle.getText("editPIN"));

    }
```

Not really the answer I was looking for because I would like to use **detachPress** and **attachPress** so if you know what I should have done in order to implement those please let me know.

Comment: While it works, my idea was to use the logic behind the text change, not the actual text element itself. Something must cause the text to change, which is the logic that also causes the button function to change. I'd be more inclined to use Marc's approach (up to you to check the flag in the controller or on the view like his solution).